# Order of elements when targeting multiple items

Tags: jquery

I have a `<ul></ul>` with over 4,000 `<li></li>` in it and I'm trying to select just a range of them. ie `[50 - 100]`.

When I target all the li's with jquery like so: `$('ul > li');` I get an array of `li`'s 4000 items long.

So I'm trying to loop from 50 thru 100 and target each of those li's:

```
for (var i = startCount; i <= stopCount; i++ ) {
  $('ul > li')[i].addClass('transparent');
}
```

But when i'm paused in the dev tools, I can see that the `$('ul > li')[50]` is near the bottom of the `ul`. I was expecting it to be the 50th or 51st item in the `ul`. Is there a way to tell if the list of UL has an order?

Comment: While modern browsers could handle this with relatively minimal trouble, you may want to reconsider how you're generating your page if you've got to load over 4,000 `<li>`s.

Comment: Check that you don't have any other unordered lists elsewhere in the page, especially before the list you care about – those are included in the selected elements.

Comment: and whatever you do, move the `$('ul > li')` call _outside_ the loop - as it is you're asking the browser to recreate that array of 4000 elements for _every_ iteration!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way you could achieve this would be to use jQuery's [**slice()**](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method.

> `slice()` - Reduce the set of matched elements to a subset specified by
>   a range of indices.

In your case, it would be:

```
$('ul > li').slice(49, 100);
// Targets the 50th to 100th ul > li elements only.
```

[**Example jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/A9z4J/1/)